# Wordpress Tags - Listing out tags to navigate to a page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've been trying to experiment with listing out all tags of my posts and using this to navigate to a page that allows you to see all posts with that tag.

At the moment I have managed to list out all tags with the following code:

```
    <ul class="category-filters menu">
        <?php

            $tags  = get_terms( array(  'taxonomy' => 'post_tag') );

            if ($tags) {

                foreach($tags as $tag) {
                    echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
                }
            }

        ?>
    </ul>
```

So this successfully lists all the tags that are in the database however I am stuck on getting them to then link to the Achieve page that will list all the selected tag posts.

Is this doable? I've done this before with categories quite easily but my client has annoyingly requested them to be tags. If you think it would be better to use categories instead of tags please give me some information into why this is better.

Many thanks